# What changes can be made to a whistle to change these variables?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow

I have read that the longer the whistle the lower the pitch and the shorter the whistle the higher the pitch.

But there are other factors. Pressure, size of the inlet, size of the outlet, diameter of the whistle... what changes occur to the whistle when these variables are changed?

More importantly, is there a way to change the threshold of when the whistle starts making noise?

For example: I want a whistle that only makes noise between 1 and 2 pounds per sqft of pressure. Outside that range it is quiet. Is it possible?

The source of the 20 mph airflow is after the whistle and increases in pressure over time, 30+ days, so when the pressure goes beyond a specific point, I'd like a whistle so I can hear it. What variables need to be considered when designing a whistle that can do this? And how would you do this?

Comment: What sources have you used as you mention “read”?

Comment: I've been googling and read that off American whistle but that wasn't helpful. been looking for a white paper or something.

Comment: What is a white paper? Paper comes in many colours...

Comment: "white paper" is a research paper

Comment: Ah - I thought white papers was a term used for those government papers that don’t come to anything...

Comment: any thoughts on my question or any research papers you can point to?

Comment: This is a good start : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/357436/how-do-i-calculate-the-perfect-whistle-design

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited to music.SE  or perhaps physics.SE

Comment: Physics SE told me to put the question here, because it has to do with building the whistle, not the theory of it which would be physics SE

Comment: It is a fair question but there are so many designs of whistles possible and therefore there are not really clear 'variables' I think you should reformulate your question by explaining the type of whistle you are talking about and which variables are you interested to vary... also there are too many questions in your list, it will be hard to reply if we only know the answer to one.

Comment: @ Jonathan - I appreciate your reply but which whistle type would you suggest  if I want a whistle to make noise from 20mph wind?