# Which Whistle Type works with the lowest PSI?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, acoustics

I'm working on a project where we are trying to prototype a whistle that works at the lowest possible air pressure and still produce an audible sound.

Any suggestions on whistle type? and any additional factors or insight that might help, would be appreciated.

Assume, Open air 72 degree Fahrenheit environment using very consistent airflow of regular 72 degree Fahrenheit air.

Comment: See this : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/18784/10902

Comment: Air pressure in a vacuum?  Is pressure constant regardless of volume used?  Is it literally air?   What temperature?

Comment: Updated Question to answer yours

Comment: if it is "open air", that is by definition atmospheric  pressure. Maybe you need to draw a picture or something.

Comment: I think you miss understood the question. pressure being the air applied to the inlet of the whistle. For example a 27mph wind would apply a pressure of 2 pounds per square feet.

Comment: Where do you get 27mph wind would apply a pressure of 2 pounds per square feet?   I do not have the rep to down vote yet.

Comment: @Exclusiveicon so what do you think the pressure is at the outlet?

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/18784/10902

Comment: Also see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/18834/10902

Comment: Round and round the mulberry bush....

Comment: I see you are asking a lot of questions about whistles. It seems like you're creating an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and you want the whistle to do something very specific. If you can tell us what you want to do with the whistle, maybe we can be of better assistance.

Comment: @ Charl Pretorious, I'm trying to find some type of whistle that can make a noise from less then 25mph wind. so basically if I hold the whistle out my car window and drive 25 mph it will make a audible noise above 45 dB

Answer (score 1):

[Native american flutes](http://www.flutopedia.com/refs/Goss_2013_IntraoralPressureInEthnicWindInstruments.pdf) from: Intraoral Pressure in Ethnic Wind Instruments Clinton F. Goss.

This study measured intraoral pressure when playing six classes of ethnic wind instruments (N = 149): Native American flutes (n = 71) and smaller samples of ethnic duct flutes, reed instruments, reedpipes, overtone whistles, and overtone flutes.

Comment: @agentp Collect 1000 rep, so you will be able to edit anything. I unfortunately mis-clicked your review (I should have rejected it), but you can still fix it by removing your unneeded comment, and fixing some other things in the post (convert the URL to a link, capital letters, and so on). If you really want to insert something invisible into a post, you can insert a html comment (`<!-- comment -->`). But it is unneeded in this case, because the post needs many fixes besides yours, too.

Comment: @peterh glad to fix if someone will clear the pending edit review.

Comment: @agentp O.k.! By improving an edit can I make it accepted on the spot. :-) Tyvm :-)